# PHP equivalent to python 'site-packages'

Tags: php

Where should I put a php library (in my current case https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) in order to have it accessible system wide?

Does PHP require me to just dump files in the directory and subdirectories of the $(pwd) that php is executed in and use paths to tell php where everything is? or is there a php equivalent to Python site-packages where all that path and loading boilerplate is done away with and i can just call it knowing its loaded every time I execute PHP?

Comment: I know its a noob type question - But I have never used PHP before other than taking care of a mediawiki or wordpress install, which is being a sysadmin not programming. So I'm at a loss here & I wasn't able to google my way to an answer.

Comment: A common default path was `/usr/share/php` for the include_path. But there's no autoloading with that. And absolute paths or per-vhost setups are more common.

Comment: @mario you may want to post that as an answer, since it pretty much is one. And you deserve the votes as such.